# Converting an "NS.time" from plist to an actual time

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

I could find the following data in a plist file:

[image]

`"NS.time"` is a key to a number value.

```
NSLog(@"Type: %@", [[obj objectForKey:@"NS.time"] class]);
NSLog(@"My dictionary: %@", obj);
```

---

```
2014-10-09 11:04:49.409 MyApp[3792:303] Type: __NSCFNumber
2014-10-09 10:34:46.393 MyApp[3644:303] My dictionary: {
    "NS.time" = "434488287.651975";
}
```

Are these seconds? Milliseconds? Microseconds?
How can I get a proper time information out of it?

**Edit**:

I found what could be the right date using Python:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=434488287.651975)
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 8, 19, 11, 27, 651975)
```

How can I do this using Objective-C?

Comment: Who put the info in the plist?

Comment: that looks like seconds since reference date, usually the reference date is 1.1.2001 or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an NSDate for 2001, 1, 1.
2. Use NSDate's `- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds` to get the new date.
   `NSDate *tagDate = [referenceDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:434488287.651975];`

---

**Edit by OP:**

Here is the complete code I used:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [[obj objectForKey:@"NS.time"] doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:interval];
```

[`dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:) is very useful in that case. It creates and returns an `NSDate` object set to a given number of seconds from the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.